# Send mail and download the file when click on DOWNLOAD button ?

Tags: php

1) When i click on DOWNLOAD button only file get downloaded...

2)  And when i add " onClick="return sendMail('. $id .')""   in  tag and "return false " in script only mail is sent

```
         how can get both the facility on a single click ?         
         // DOWNLOAD LINK
    echo '<a href="'.$path.'" onClick="sendMail('. $id .')" class="links">Download</a>';

       //SCRIPT for sending mail
              <script>
               function sendMail(str)
                {alert(str);
              if (str=="")
              {
             document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML="";
                   return;
                  }
              if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
             {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
              xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
               }
            else
             {// code for IE6, IE5
            xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                }
            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
               {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
               {
              document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
                }
              }
          xmlhttp.open("POST","sendMail.php?q="+str,true);
           xmlhttp.send();
        //return false; 
             }
         </script>

       // sendMail.php

         <?php include_once("includes/connection.php");

          $q = ($_REQUEST['q']);


            $sqlid="SELECT * FROM files_table WHERE id = '".$q."'";
           $result = mysqli_query($conn,$sqlid);
           $row=mysqli_fetch_array($result);
          //collect data from table
          $id=$row['id'];
          $email =$row['user_email'];
          $message=$row['message'];
          $file_type=$row['file_type'];
           $download=$row['file_name'];
          $time=$row['time'];


          $to=$email;
      $from = "support@print.com"; // sender
           $subject = $id.'   '.$message;
          $message = "  

          'Dear Sir,

          Greetings from Printing! India's leading Printing company.
         Please let us know for any queries or concerns. We are here to serve you better.
           Assuring you of our best services at all times and looking forward to a long and pleasant association

Regards,
Team Printing";

      // message lines should not exceed 70 characters (PHP rule), so wrap it
          $message = wordwrap($message, 70);
        // send mail
        mail($to,$subject,$message,"From: $from\n");
         echo "Mail Sent"; 

         ?>


      //download.php
             <?php             
            //Set the time out to 0
           set_time_limit(0);

           //Path to the download file
           $Location_to_download_files = 'downloads/'.$_REQUEST['file_to_download'];

          function File_Downloads($file, $name, $mime_type='')
            {
              //Check premission for the file 
                if(!is_readable($file)) die('Sorry, the file could not found or its inaccessible.');

                 $size = filesize($file);
                $name = rawurldecode($name);

                /* Find out the MIME type. You can add any other required download file format of your choice or remove if necessary */
                 $known_mime_types = array(
                  //Programs Extensions
                 "html" => "text/html",
                 "htm" => "text/html",

                //Archives
                   "zip" => "application/zip",

              //Documents
            "pdf" => "application/pdf",
            "doc" => "application/msword",
            "docx" => "application/msword",
             "xls" => "application/vnd.ms-excel",
            "ppt" => "application/vnd.ms-powerpoint",
             "txt" => "text/plain",

              //Executables
             "exe" => "application/octet-stream",

              //Images
            "gif" => "image/gif",
           "png" => "image/png",
            "jpeg"=> "image/jpg",
           "jpg" =>  "image/jpg",
            "php" => "text/plain",

  //Audio
 "mp3" => "audio/mpeg",
 "wav" => "audio/x-wav",

 //Video
 "mpeg" => "video/mpeg",
 "mpg" => "video/mpeg",
 "mpe" => "video/mpeg",
 "mov" => "video/quicktime",
 "avi" => "video/x-msvideo"
    );

        if($mime_type == "")
          {
           $file_extension = strtolower(substr(strrchr($file,"."),1));
            if(array_key_exists($file_extension, $known_mime_types))
           {
           $mime_type=$known_mime_types[$file_extension];
          } 
            else 
            {
            $mime_type="application/force-download";
            };
             };

          //turn off output buffering to decrease cpu usage
          @ob_end_clean(); 

        // required for IE, otherwise Content-Disposition may be ignored
           if(ini_get("zlib.output_compression"))
          ini_set("zlib.output_compression", "Off");

        header("Content-Type: " . $mime_type);
           header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='".$name."'");
       header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
         header("Accept-Ranges: bytes");

      /* The three lines below basically make the 
            download non-cacheable */
            header("Cache-control: private");
             header("Pragma: private");
            header("Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT");

           // multipart-download and download resuming support
            if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_RANGE']))
            {
         list($a, $range) = explode("=",$_SERVER['HTTP_RANGE'],2);
          list($range) = explode(",",$range,2);
          list($range, $range_end) = explode("-", $range);
          $range=intval($range);
          if(!$range_end) {
        $range_end=$size-1;
        } else {
    $range_end=intval($range_end);
      }

          $new_length = $range_end-$range+1;
          header("HTTP/1.1 206 Partial Content");
          header("Content-Length: $new_length");
           header("Content-Range: bytes $range-$range_end/$size");
           } else {
        $new_length=$size;
        header("Content-Length: ".$size);
         }  

         /* Will output the file itself */
          $chunksize = 1*(1024*1024); //You can change this if you wish
         $bytes_send = 0;
            if ($file = fopen($file, 'r'))
         {
        if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_RANGE']))
          fseek($file, $range);

      while(!feof($file) && (!connection_aborted()) && ($bytes_send<$new_length))
         {
    $buffer = fread($file, $chunksize);
    print($buffer);
    flush();
    $bytes_send += strlen($buffer);
       }
       fclose($file);
          } 
         else
        //If no permissiion
            die('Error - The file you attempted to download can not be openned at the moment. Please try again or contact the site admin if this problem persist.');
  //die
     die();
      }

           //Call the function to download with file path,file name and file type
     File_Downloads($Location_to_download_files, $_REQUEST['file_to_download'], 'text/plain');

?>
```

Comment: I've just redone the entire formatting of your code. Seriously, it's so much easier to read code if it's properly structured and indented. You are using about 4 different styles of indentation, this makes it very likely that you will forget a curly brace at some point, or forget what level of loop/structure/scope/etc. you're in while developing. Stick to a single style to make your own life (and that of everyone having to read your code later) easier.

Answer (score 0):

Remove Onclick from Donwload link(href),

and call that function in to php function 
          `function File_Downloads($file, $name, $mime_type='')
             { 
              //Your send mail function 
              echo '<script>  function sendMail(str)  {  //your content } </script>';
            }`